# How to get the Hierarchy recursively in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphism, many-to-many, polymorphic-associations

I have 2 tables i.e. `users` and `user_managers`, with the following structure and data:

**users**

| id | name | employee_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Employee One | ACB1234 |
| 2 | Employee Two | XYZ1234 |
| 3 | Employee Three | EFG1234 |
| 4 | Employee Four | HIJ1234 |

**user_managers**

| id | user_id | manager_of_user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 5 | 4 |

I want a recursive function to get the complete chain of the managers. For example, if query for `user_id = 4`, I should get the following result:

**result**

| user_id | name | employee_id | comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Employee One | ABC1234 | user managed by 4 |
| 2 | Employee Two | XYZ1234 | user managed by 1 |
| 3 | Employee Three | EFG1234 | managd by user 2 |
| 5 | Employee Five | JKL1234 | manager of user 4 |

The table above is just for the clarification, I am looking for a recursive function to get the above result.
I have tried the below solution but it is working for only 1 level.

```
public static function getCompleteChain(User $user)
    {
        $managerUsers = $user->managers;

        foreach ($managerUsers as $manager) {
            $manager->user = User::where('employee_id', $manager->manager_of_user_id)->first();
            self::getCompleteChain($manager->user);
        }
        return $managerUsers;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why does it need to be recursive? .. you could use nested sets or closure tables instead of an adjacency list system

Comment: @lagbox, can you please give me an example? Will there be a way to put a stopping point in the nested loops?

Comment: sorry I probably jumped the gun on that, didn't see the pivot table ... can a user have multiple direct managers or only one?

Comment: @lagbox, only one direct manager in my case

Comment: i might look into nested sets for that type of hierarchy ... allows you to deal with ordered trees without needing to do recursive queries, they have a cost for insertion/deletions/moves though ... just an option to not have to do things recursively so you could do a single query to get all parents or descendants regardless of depth

Comment: Let me look into this @lagbox